# Set size of figure with 3d subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, matplotlib-3d

I have a figure where I want to plot a 3d scatter and a normal plot in 2 subplots.
I use this code

```
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
```

then I use ax and ax2 to plot my data in the right place. But The figure I get is too small, how can I make it bigger?, adding `figsize=(w, h)` to the first line doesn't have any effect and results in an error if I add it to the second or third line.:

> AttributeError: 'Axes3DSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_figsize'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130823/set-matplotlib-3d-plot-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding `figsize=(w,h)` to the first line should do the trick. What do you mean by "it has no effect"?

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig1=plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
ax11=fig1.add_subplot(211,projection='3d')
ax12=fig1.add_subplot(212)

fig1.get_size_inches()
# array([ 8.,  5.])

fig2=plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax21=fig1.add_subplot(211,projection='3d')
ax22=fig1.add_subplot(212)

fig2.get_size_inches()
# array([ 4.,  4.])

fig1.savefig('fig1.png',dpi=300)
fig2.savefig('fig2.png',dpi=300)
```

After saving figures as png's at 300dpi:

```
$ identify fig1.png
>>> fig1.png PNG 2400x1500 2400x1500+0+0 8-bit sRGB 118KB 0.000u 0:00.000

$ identify fig2.png
>>> fig2.png PNG 1200x1200 1200x1200+0+0 8-bit sRGB 86.9KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Changing `figsize` has no effect. The trick is to increase `dpi`.