# set_aspect('equal') warping some 3D functions but not others?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I have a function that takes in strings representing 3D functions. When I plot functions like a torus or sphere using `set_aspect('equal')` they look [great](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Wt9.png), otherwise without set_aspect() they look [warped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGBTz.png) and elongated. On the flip side, when I plot the other function mentioned below, set_aspect() makes it terribly warped/scaled out [beyond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzZaM.png) recognition,  whereas without set_aspect() it looks [great](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8SOP.png). I have tried fiddling around with the limits as well as box aspect/set_aspect('auto') to no avail. I want my function to be able to handle a wide variety of math functions, so I'm trying to avoid hardcoding things that would work for some functions but not others. Working in VSCode Matplotlib 3.7.1.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import sympy
import numpy as np



def queryMatplotlib3dEq(sol, ax):

    lhs, rhs = sol.split("=")

    def f(x, y):
        if (lhs == "z"):
            return eval(rhs)
        else:
            return eval(lhs)

    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 10000)
    y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 10000)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    if (lhs == 'z' or rhs == 'z'):
        Z = f(X, Y)
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap="viridis")
  
    # ax.set_box_aspect((1, 1, 1))


    #Removing this makes some functions look bad, and other functions look good
    # ax.set_aspect('equal')


    # ax.relim()
    # ax.autoscale_view()




#With set_aspect('equal') these looks great, without it they look warped
# qVal = "(8- (x**2 + y**2)**(1/2))**2 + z**2 = 3"
# qVal="x**2+y**2+z**2=100"

# #With set_aspect('equal') this looks terribly warped, without it it looks great
qVal="x*y**3 -y*x**3"


x, y, z = sympy.symbols('x y z')

if ('=' in qVal):
    lhs, rhs = qVal.split('=')
    eq = sympy.Eq(eval(lhs), eval(rhs))
else:
    eq = sympy.Eq(eval('z'), eval(qVal))


sols = ['z=' + v.replace('sqrt', 'np.sqrt')
        for v in map(str, sympy.solve(eq, z))]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

for sol in sols:
    print(sol)
    queryMatplotlib3dEq(sol, ax)


plt.show()
```

Comment: What Matplotlib does is what you've asked it to do. If, say, 0<x<10, 0<y<10 and 0<z<5000 and you ask that all three axes are rendered at the same scale, well, they are rendered at the same scale and the x-y plane becomes negligible in the drawing. I think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73749399/2749397) could be useful to you.

Comment: @gboffi I see youre referring to the x and y linespace that I set. I'm sure the better way would be to set it dynamically depending on the function to be plotted, but I'm not sure how I would go about implementing that.

Comment: Matplotlib has a very good implementation of dynamically scaling the 3D plot, if you have a fixed domain for x and y you can set the aspect ratio only for that plane, as explained and shown in the answer I've linked above, and let Matplotlib do the rest.